# How to programm a standalone MSP430g2553 via a com port?

Tags: microcontroller, communication, msp430, launchpad

The MSP430 is a dirt cheap MCU and i thought that if i could make a barebone launchpad out of that which can be programed directly via the PC COM port or a virtual one. So is it possible to program it with the energia IDE on the com port?

Comment: TI sent me a genuine lanchpad for $4.30 (free international shipping) I think the launchapd das an ARM M0 on it that converts the serial to SPI for programmng.

Comment: @Jasen- why would serial be converted to SPI? Moreover even if it is so then how would i do that from a com port i.e. what protocol would be implemented?

Comment: it's not actually SPI, but something called spy-bi-wire that uses a clock line and a birectional data line, the serial port has enough I/O to drive that, but serial over usb has a max bit-bang rate of about 1000 transitions per second which if it's acceptable to the MSP430 would be painfully slow

Comment: Oh yeah heard about that, the speed isnt the factor now but can i use the SBW protocol in energia via the com port?

Comment: The MCU on the MSP launchpad is MSP430F1612 (might be another variant on newer models) essentially, the UIF430 JTAG adapter. Spy-Bi-Wire is done via dedicated SBWTDIO (Test) and SBWCLK (Reset) lines. To use a UART, you need to use the BSL pins.

Comment: @LiorBilia- thanks for that, if i use the bsl pins then how to setup the energia IDE or the CC Studio to function on the com port with the bsl protocol?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The details of the MSP430 series boot strap loader (BSL) can be found here:

http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau319i/slau319i.pdf

You will need to connect RST and TEST lines to DTR and RTS as described.

Energia uses `mspdebug` to program the Launchpads using the `rf2500` or `tilib` options. The `flash-bsl` option should be about the program the MSP430g2553 via the COM port with the RST and TEST lines connected.

In the Energia folder under `hardware` then `msp430` there is a file called `boards.txt`. You should add a new entry for your board with the upload setting set to `flash-bsl`.

e.g.

```
##############################################################
baremsp430g2553.name=msp430g2553 (16MHz)
baremsp430g2553.upload.protocol=flash-bsl
baremsp430g2553.upload.maximum_size=16384
baremsp430g2553.build.mcu=msp430g2553
baremsp430g2553.build.f_cpu=16000000L
baremsp430g2553.build.core=msp430
baremsp430g2553.build.variant=bare
baremsp430g2553.upload.maximum_ram_size=512
```

Note: I have not done this myself, but it is how the Arduino system is modified. I'll be putting together a custom msp430fr5969 board in a few days and following the same process.

Of course, you *do not need Energia* to program the chips. You can make a normal msp430-gcc build system and use the Energia core libraries and compiler. I do this myself using Netbeans and it is well worth the effort to set up. The "Processing" IDE (what Arduino and Energia's IDE are based on) is great for a quick mash up but terrible for any serious work, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for any msp430 that had a bootloader with serial upload capability. The standard method of programming would be spy-bi-wire, which does not use the serial pins.

Comment: I wanna use the serial pins, maybe with bsl protocol. And also some schematics would help

Comment: And does the energia IDE support the BSL protocol?