# Programming MSP430G2553 with Raspberry Pi 2

Tags: raspberry-pi, i2c, spi, msp430

So, i want to program a msp430g2553 microcontroller with raspberry pi 2. 
Since i don't want to use any IDE i would like to do it with clean C and terminal, without any external libraries like wiringPi etc. , just the microcontrollers one.

My questions are:

- Can i do this with common interfaces like I2C or SPI?
- Or should i use the JTAG interface to do this?

This is the first microcontroller that i am trying to program.I've seen that you can program an ATtiny85 with raspberry over SPI. Does all the microcontrollers have this functionalities or it is device specific.

Comment: See also http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149704/how-to-programm-a-standalone-msp430g2553-via-a-com-port : this stuff is *very* device-specific.

Comment: You mean directly instead of using a programmer via usb?

Comment: Yes, I want to do it directly without any external programmer device. Just by wiring the raspberry pi and the msp430.

Comment: If mspdebug has been ported to the R-Pi, then I'd look at the EZ-430 or the G2553's Launchpad as a sub-$10 adapter between USB and the MSP430's SBW interface (a 2-wire subset of JTAG).

Answer (score 2):

You can flash it via serial port, as @pjc50 suggested. Here is a part of a makefile I used for a msp430 project:

```
msp430-gcc -Wall -mmcu=msp430g2553 -o foo.elf some.c files.c and.c headers.h
msp430-objcopy -O ihex foo.elf foo.hex
msp430-objdump -DS foo.elf > foo.lst    # produces an assembler listing, optional
python2 -m msp430.bsl.uart -e -p /dev/ttyUSB0 -PV foo.hex -r
```

This requires the packets `msp430-gcc`,`-binutils`,`-mcu`,`-libc` and `python-msp430-tools` to be installed. You will need to connect RST and TEST lines to DTR and RTS as described in [slau319](http://www.ti.com/lit/ug/slau319k/slau319k.pdf) or [this related answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/149704/how-to-programm-a-standalone-msp430g2553-via-a-com-port).